# Google API Gateway: Provide API key in header

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-gateway

I'm trying to setup Google API Gateway to use an API key that callers send in the header.
My api config yaml looks like this:

```yaml
...
securityDefinitions:
  api_key_header:
    type: apiKey
    name: key
    in: header
  api_key_query:
    type: apiKey
    name: key
    in: query
paths:
  /foo-header:
    get:
      summary: Test foo endpoint
      operationId: testGet-header
      x-google-backend:
        address: "<backend address>"
        protocol: h2
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      security:
        - api_key_header: []
      responses:
        204:
          description: A successful response
  /foo-query:
    get:
      summary: Test foo endpoint
      operationId: testGet-header
      x-google-backend:
        address: "<backend address>"
        protocol: h2
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      security:
        - api_key_query: []
      responses:
        204:
          description: A successful response
```

I expect both calls, `/foo-header` and `/foo-query` to fail with 401 status if a valid API key is not provided via header or query parameter.

But in a fact only `/foo-query` behaves as expected.
Requests to `/foo-header` pass to the backend even when the API key is not provided in request header.

Do I have issue with the config, or is it the Google API Gateway that doesn't work properly when API key is provided in request header?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `in` is `header`, the `name` should be `x-api-key`.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations#api_key_definition_limitations

Comment: What if I need to set a customer header name? The reason is that the security header name is hardcoded on the caller side so I need to configure a matching name on my (API) side. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Google API Gateway *should* work fine when the API key is provided in request header since the Google API Gateway documentation states:

> A developer generates an API key in a project in the Cloud Console and embeds that key in every call to your API as a **query** parameter or in a request **header**.

However, I was able to reproduce the behavior you reported, thus I don't think that there is something wrong in your configuration.

For that I'd been following the GCP [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/quickstart-console) for the Google API Gateway, modifying it slightly so that my OpenAPI spec would also have 2 paths: one is looking for a key in **query** parameters, while another in the request **header**.

```
paths:
  /foo-header:
    get:
      summary: Test security
      operationId: headerkey
      x-google-backend:
        address: [MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION_1]
      security:
      - api_key_header: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
  /foo-query:
    get:
      summary: Test security
      operationId: querykey
      x-google-backend:
        address: [MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION_2]
      security:
      - api_key_query: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key_header:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "header"
  api_key_query:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
```

Just like you, I could see the requests to the `/foo-header` pass to the backend even when there was no API key provided.

---

I would suggest you to [report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) this issue on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/), so that it would be reviewed by an appropriate GCP engineering team.